# save values on elements with same property javascript

Tags: javascript

I have an array of several entries with some of them with same name .All entries have location but one is empty.I want to save the same value of location into all entries of the array for same user. How can I do that?

```
      array=[{
                    user: angelos,
                    user_id: 121212,
                    date: 12/12/12,
                    profile_img: cfdf,
                    text: nhkjhgjtdkghd,
                    url: g.htm,
                    location:Romania
                },{
                    user: angelos,
                    user_id: 121212,
                    date: 12/12/12,
                    profile_img: cfdf,
                    text: nhkjhgjsdfsadstdkghd,
                    url: g.htm,
                    location:""
                },{
                    user: Mike,
                    user_id: 121212,
                    date: 12/12/12,
                    profile_img: cfdf,
                    text: nhkjhgjtdkghd,
                    url: g.htm,
                    location:New York
                },{
                    user: Mike,
                    user_id: 121212,
                    date: 12/12/12,
                    profile_img: cfdf,
                    text: nhkjhgjsdfsadstdkghd,
                    url: g.htm,
                    location:""
                }];
```

Comment: do you know if first user always have location? Is it possible for user instances to have different locations in array ?

Comment: yes first user always always have location.yes users have different loations from each other

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, for each user, store its non-empty location. Then, in the second pass, simply set empty locations based on the stored `user -> location` map.

```
var userLocationMap = {};
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  if (array[i].location) {
    userLocationMap[array[i].user] = array[i].location;
  }
}

for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  if (!array[i].location) {
    array[i].location = userLocationMap[array[i].user];
  }
}
```